# Finding the sum of an average column in mysql

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

How do I find the sum of an average?  For example:

```
select avg(app_loan_amnt) 
from receipt_history
union 
select sum(avg(app_ln_amnt))
```

*I know the last union statement is incorrect, but how would I do that?*

Comment: What does `sum of the average` mean?  Will you first break the data into groups, and find the average of each, and then sum those averages?

Comment: No, in the first select statement it finds the average and in the second select statement it finds the sum of the columns that have the average values, I didnt see where it had to be down voted but please i need help

Comment: be careful when adding averages, as usually it gives an incorrect value unless all groups average over the same # of items. For example, one group could be just one item with value 2 and another group could be 1000000 items with value 10. Your sum of averages would return 12, which is not really useful

Comment: @Rodolfo good point **that the OP should clarify**, but not sure if that's "incorrect", necessarily.  Maybe just strange.

Comment: @MattFenwick yes I didn't say it was incorrect, but something I usually see when people work with averages. Well, I did say incorrect but what I meant was more like 'useless' :)

Comment: thank you but yes I have groupings etc but i just posted a shaved down version due to the fact that I am having trouble there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

1. get the average of some value, when grouping the data a certain way
2. sum those averages

You can accomplish this with a subquery:

```
select
  sum(group_avg) as total
from (
  select avg(<some_value>) as group_avg
  from receipt_history
  group by <column>
) q;
```

You'll need to fill in what you're averaging and how you're grouping the data.

Comment: seem like what I am looking for Ill try it and let you know